# I Want To Eliminate %20 In My Echo Return

Tags: php, wordpress

In my .php file I use the following to return the category that my posts are in:

`<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>`

The category title is then returned in my URL. HOWEVER, since my category is two words ("South Africa"), the URL reads: "south%20africa" instead of "southafrica".

I know that the "%20" is being inserted because urls cannot have breaks. Is there a way to edit the above `<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>` to return the category title but eliminate any breaks?

Comment: see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php - Also, you want "south africa" not "southafrica" right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo urldecode("south%20africa");
```

or

```
echo str_replace('%20', '', "south%20africa");
```

Comment: I have this right now: <?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>

I want it to return "southafrica" and not "south%20africa"